# incorrect answer in beginner name program, Python

Tags: python, python-2.x

```
    name = raw_input("Insert Name: ")

    typedname = "Brock", "brock"

    name == typedname

    if name != "Brock" "brock":
        print "Access Denied"
```

Every time I run the code I get access denied.
What's causing this error and how can i rectify it?

Comment: how are you running this script ? from command line ?

Comment: `name == typename` is a no-op because it is a comparison, try `name = typename`.  `typename` is a tuple because of the comma, so `name` will also be a tuple.  But in the comparison you don't have a comma, so you are comparing a tuple with a string.

Comment: @sa77 I use repl.it at the moment

Comment: @THC__ , what is your question?It will get denied because you dont have a else statement to do other part of the code.

Comment: Maybe you just want to drop the line `name == typedname` (what did you expect that to do?) and write the comparison as `if name not in typedname:`.

Comment: @THC__, DONT. If you got the solution for your answer, post it as a answer and do not change it in the original question.

Comment: @THC__, revert the orignal question and post your solution as an answer.Or for the betterment of the community accept the answer provided by the SO community.

Comment: @WhiteShadow My mistake friend. I'm new here wasn't aware but that makes sense,

Comment: @THC__, it happens. Try reading [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You used

```
name == typedname
```

but your intent was to *assign*, not to *compare*. Use `=` instead of `==`:

```
name = typedname
```

But it is still *logically wrong* (it *rewrites* the answer from an user), so don't use it - simply *omit this command*.

Another problem is in the command

```
if name != "Brock" "brock":
```

You probably wanted

```
if name not in typedname:
```

Comment: Thank you. I used what you mentioned followed by an else statement to read "Welcome Brock" if the name matched.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `"Brock", "brock"` and `"Brock" "brock"` are not the same thing.

`"Brock", "brock"` is a tuple containing two strings, while `"Brock" "brock"` is a single string (`"Brockbrock"`).  Literal strings separated only by whitespace are joined together as they are read.
That's why

```
if name not in typedname:
```

was (apparently) what you wanted.

Comment: If literal strings separated only by whitespace are joined together, "Brock" "brock" should become "Brockbrock", and not "Brockrock".

Answer (score 0):

Here is the source code that I figured out after reading a few replies.
 The main problem was I used "!=" instead of "if name not in" also I left out the else statement, but I knew that. I'm taking small steps to see where I can end up.

```
    name = raw_input("Insert Name: ")

    typedname = "Brock", "brock"


    if name not in typedname:
        print "Access Denied"
    else:
        print "Welcome Brock"
```

Comment: You should have accepted their answer. Anyway works this way too.